# How make this invoice component change its behavior if the user enters by clicking on a particular link from a different component

Tags: angular

I have a invoice component which shows all invoices by default and if user clicks on More Info then `this.showAllInvoice`s is set to false and `<ng-template #showSingleInvoice>` is shown.

```
export class InvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  invoiceDetails: String;
  singleInvoiceDetail: any;
  showAllInvoices = true;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.auth.getInvoices().subscribe((res: any)=>{
      if(res.status === 200) {
        this.invoiceDetails = res.body.data;
      }
    },(err: any)=>{
      this.loading = false;
      alert("Error Fetiching Invoice Details")
    })
  }

  moreInfo(invoiceDetail: any) {
   this.singleInvoiceDetail = invoiceDetail;
   this.showAllInvoices = false;
  }

  showAll() {
    this.showAllInvoices = true;
  }

}
```

.

```
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div *ngIf="showAllInvoices else showSingleInvoice" class="content-wrapper">
        <table class="all-invoices">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>View</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let invoiceDetail of invoiceDetails;">
            <td>{{invoiceDetail.type}}</td>
            <td>{{invoiceDetail.due_date}}</td>
            <td>$ {{invoiceDetail.total_amount}}</td>
            <td>{{invoiceDetail.status}}</td>
            <td (click)="moreInfo(invoiceDetail)"
            style="cursor: pointer;">More Info</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

<ng-template #showSingleInvoice>
   <div>Single invoice is shown</div>
    <h4 style="cursor: pointer" (click)="showAll()">Go Back To List</h4>
</ng-template>
```

There is another component which has the option to create invoice. Plan is sent as an argument at the time of click so `createInvoice` function knows which plans was clicked.
After creating the invoice `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/invoice']);` sends the user to invoice component above but that page shows all the invoices by default. I want that if the user clicks on choose plan 1 or choose plan two and then when he is directed to the invoice page then `<ng-template #showSingleInvoice>` should be shown with the data. in the invoice component data is passed from `<td (click)="moreInfo(invoiceDetail)".`  So is it possible or am I using the wrong approach and making it complicated.

```
<div class="info-box-content">
  <span class="info-box-text"></span>
  <span class="info-box-number">Plans</span>
  <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="createInvoice(Plan1)">Choose Plan 1</a><br>
  <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="createInvoice(Plan2)">Choose Plan 2</a>
</div>
```

.

```
export class DashboardHomeComponent implements OnInit {
Plan1 = {
    amount: 5.00,
    tax: 1.00,
    type: 'EMAIL_MARKETING',
    text: 0.0
  }

 Plan2 = {
    amount: 10.00,
    tax: 1.00,
    type: 'EMAIL_MARKETING',
    text: 0.0
  }


  constructor(private auth: AuthService,  private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createInvoice(plan: any){
    this.auth.createInvoice(plan).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      if(res.status==200) {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/invoice']);
      }
    }, (err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe give +1 to my accepted answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make a new route for viewing individual invoices and use route parameters in this case. See 
 [Routing and navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router) section in Angular documentation.

In a nutshell, you change your html to something like this:

```
<a routerLink="/invoice/1" >Choose Plan 1</a>
```

Then in your routing-module.ts you have a route for the individual invoices

```
const routes = [
  { path: 'invoice',  component: InvoiceListComponent},
  { path: 'invoice/:id', component: InvoiceDetailComponent }
];
```

Now in your InvoiceDetailComponent, you can fetch the "id" parameter from the url and show corresponding invoice in that template.

See [Route parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters) for detailed instructions how to get the parameter and use it.

I hope this helps!